# Find covariance when expected value of product is zero

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, covariance, random-variable

$W$ and $X$ are random variables and have the same probability space. If $E(WX)$ is zero then how can I prove that $\operatorname{cov} (W,X)$ is zero?

I know that $\operatorname{cov} (W,X) = E(WX)-E(w)E(X)$ but how we can decide what $E(W)$ and $E(X)$ are? We do not know that they are dependent or independent.

Answer (score 5):

As you correctly state, 
$$ {\rm Cov}(W, X) = E(WX) - E(W) E(X). $$
If you are given that $E(XW) = 0$, then ${\rm Cov}(W, X) =0 \iff E(W) = 0$ or $E(X) = 0$. Perhaps you should consider whether either $W$ or $X$ have expected value zero.

Comment: Yes but how we can decide whether their mean zero or not

Comment: This is entirely context-dependent. I have no way of telling you this unless you can tell me more about $W$ or $X$.

Answer (score 3):

Let's take as an example the following two discrete random variables with the following probabilities:
P(X=1)= 0.5
P(X=0)= 0.5
Y = 1 - X
(In other terms Y is dependent on X, and takes 0 if X takes 1 and takes 1 if X takes 0)
We have E(XY) = 0
E(X) = 0.5 and E(Y) = 0.5 hence COV(X,Y) = -0.25 (Hence COR(X,Y) = - 1 )

That proves that even if E(XY) = 0 that does not mean the COV(X,Y) is 0 as well.